# HTML inside XML doc doesn't display properly if first text inside element

Tags: xml, xhtml, cdata

I'm using javascript to pull data returned from an XML document. Inside this XML file are elements that may have XHTML tags inside of them. The nodevalue is not displaying when the XHTML is surrounded by CDATA tags nor when I enter &lt/&gt manually. When there is no XHTML formatting inside an element, the nodevalue displays fine.

```
<note title="criteria">
 <ul>
  <li>If patient has wide complex tachycardia and is pulseless, see VF/Pulseless VT protocol</li>
  <li>Stable VT protocol - Asymptomatic or minor symptoms (palpitations, heart racing, etc.)</li>
  <li>Unstable VT protocol – <u>HR&gt;150</u> with altered mental status changes, chest pain, hypotension, shock symptoms (cap refill &gt; 2 sec, poor peripheral pulses, cool distal extremities, diaphoresis).</li>
 </ul>
 </note>
```

I am trying not to use XSLT but is there any way else to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to see [Embedded HTML Tags Inside XML - Dev Shed](http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/embedded-html-tags-inside-xml-126100.html) and also take a look at [IE XML Data Island Functionality in NS6+ Browsers](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/xml/).

Comment: The CDATA guard works in other places, but not when it is the first thing inside the element. If there is text before the guard, the XHTML displays fine.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, this would have worked fine. For the amount of HTML inside my XML document, XSLT was the way to go...